# How to properly set One-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Suppose I have two models, one for items-to-be-repaired and other for maintenance-orders. Items-to-be-repaired are created and await for a later assignment to one maintenance-order. One maintenance-order can include several items but each item can only be assigned to a unique maintenance order.

How should I set the models so that I can select multiple items in the create form for the maintenance-order?

I am trying:

```
class ItemsToBeRepaired(models.Model):  
    maintenance_order = models.ForeignKey(MaintenanceOrder, null=True, blank=True)

class MaintenanceOrder(models.Model):
    pass
```

Is this correct?  How do you include a model field in MaintenanceOrder so that it shows in the CreateView and select multiple items to be repaired?

I apologize if this is a simple question, I am learning programming and Django, have read the documentation and other questions in StackOverflow but still can't figure out the correct way to do this. I appreciate you help.

Comment: I assume you are planning to put more in the MaintenanceOrder than just "pass". Otherwise, yes, that will give you the type of relationship you want.

Comment: Sure. Then every model has its own fields as required by the project. The thing is that with those models I can add the maintenance order to the instance of ItemsToBeRepaired in a CreateView for the latter, but I can't add items to be repaired in a form for an instance of MaintenanceOrder in a CreateView for this one.

Comment: Maybe I need an intermediate model?

Comment: Hmm. To be honest, I do not have much experience with the CreateViews. i would suggest adding the django-views tag to your question and see if it gets more skilled attention. :)

Comment: Your models are correct. To create the form you want, look into [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Note that the example there exactly matches your scenario.